# Spring vs EJB - Distribution between the apps ( Remoting )

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, ejb-3.1

Analyzing Spring and EJB 3.x to migrate a existing apps from EJB 2.1 deployed in JBOSS 5.1 with Java 6.

I see many advocates for Spring as that showed the path to EJB 3 despite not being J2EE standard.

However when it comes to distribution, I feel EJB 3.x  has bit edge over SPRING as it has simplified JNDI lookup and WebService distribution. @EJB and Webservice annotation makes them further easier. Can use JNDI lookup for Java application and WebService calls if requires.

Looking forward different views regarding this, thanks

Found a nice comparison, http://www.future-processing.pl/blog/another-one-on-spring-framework-and-enterprise-javabeans/

Comment: Spring provides multiple solutions for distribution, http, webservices, rmi, rmi-iiop, hessian, burlap. Checkout spring remoting. Also you might want to even reconsider distribution (first rule of distributed computing, don't do it!).

Comment: Will check the String remoting. Thanks for the headsup. "Also you might want to even reconsider distribution (first rule of distributed computing, don't do it!)". Sharing/Reusing the resources between the apps is not good!?

Comment: Distribution adds complexity, if that is acceptable go with it. If you don't really need distribution (especially the RMI kind is painful) don't do it.

Comment: thanks again. The current setup having 4 apps sharing the existing EJB 2.1 packs. Major on persistence and also for some business utilities. Seems in EJB 3.1 the JNDI look up  simplified for registering and calling the resources.

Comment: EJB3+ is a major overhaul and improvement of the EJB stuff. If you can ditch EJB 2.1 and refactor to 3.x it will me much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring has different options for distribution (also known as remoting), different options are explained in [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html).

Out of the box Spring supports remoting via

- RMI
- RMI-IIOP
- JMS
- HTTP
- Hessian
- Burlap
- JMX

You can also create a SOAP based webservice using [Spring WS](http://projects.spring.io/spring-ws/) (or Apache CXF or...) and you could use Spring MVC to expose endpoint through Rest.

The [Spring AMQP](http://projects.spring.io/spring-amqp/) project also supports remoting over RabbitMQ.

If you want to go really flexible you can always have a look at [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/).

And if you want you can always combine Spring with EJB. Advantage of this is you get distributed transactions (if you want to use those) and management of resources by your application server. With the Spring Remoting options (most of them) you would have to solve this in a different way.

Basically I would say Spring offers more freedom in choice of distribution then Java EE with EJB or webservices (JAX-WS and JAX-RS) does.